# Check whether file has content other than header

Tags: python, pandas

this is probably a stupid question, but how can i check whether a file has any content other than the header, without loading the entire file into memory.

My requirement is like this, i have a list of files. Without loading the entire file i want to check whether it has any content other than the header. If it does, then open the file and do append operation. Else continue on to the next file.
This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

InFiles = ["Input1.txt","Input2.txt"]
OpFile = "Output.txt"
Header = False;

for i in range(0, len(InFiles)):
    with open(InFiles[i]) as f:
        line1, line2 = next(f), next(f)
    if line2 is not None and len(line2) > 0:
        df = pd.read_csv(InFiles[i], dtype=str)
        if not Header:
            df.to_csv(OpFile, mode='a', index=False, header=True)
            Header = True
        else:
            df.to_csv(OpFile, mode='a', index=False, header=False)
```

Here, when i try to read the line after header i.e., `line2 = next(f)` it throws an exception. What i want to do is if a line after header is not there, then execution should continue with the next file.

How should i do this?

EDIT:: Trying COLDSPEEEDS solution:

```
for i in range(0, len(InFiles)):
    df = pd.read_csv(opFilename, dtype=str, nrows=1)
        if df is not None and len(df) > 0:
        df = pd.read_csv(InFiles[i], dtype=str)
        if not Header:
            df.to_csv(OpFile, mode='a', index=False, header=True)
            Header = True
        else:
            df.to_csv(OpFile, mode='a', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: `pd.read_csv(InFiles[i], dtype=str, nrows=1)`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: will this load the entire file into memory?

Comment: No, just the first row.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ:I checked out your answer. What i'm trying to do is if the file contains a record apart from the header, then do operation. Else continue with the next file. But your solution would throw an exception if file does not contain a record.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: plz check my edit. Can u suggest a way to handle this?

Comment: I solved it, could u put ur comment as an answer, so that i can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could specify `nrows=1` to read just the first row, and then do a length check:

```
df = pd.read_csv(InFiles[i], dtype=str, nrows=1)
if not len(df):
    ...
```